# How to debug SystemJS ENOENT no such error error in Webpack 2.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, systemjs, jspm

After upgrading to `Webpack 2.x`, I'm getting this error, during compilation and re-compilation (in **HMR mode**):

```
(SystemJS) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...
```

[image]

Have anybody found a way to fix that? Here is the **source code**:

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate/tree/webpack2 (see PR [#102](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate/pull/102))

Comment: The error is there is "no such file or directory." In other words, it cannot find what you are asking it to find. So a path is wrong somewhere. In this case, `footer.js` seems to be trying to load `babel-loader`. But look at the path that failed to load: `c:\Projects\...C:\Projects`. That definitely doesn't seem right.